# How to change event in slider

Tags: jquery

I want to change jquery event in the way that i turn off the slider and insert (keep) link to the another page. First page http://newlove.loveandbrands.rs/wp/en/artist-list/ and second page http://newlove.loveandbrands.rs/wp/en/dixon-en/

I tried with this code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $( ".qodef-artist" ).off( "click");    
});
```

But i only enable slider on the click, but i cant preserve a link. I used to functions like append, but i didn't have any results with them.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the slider? Have you contacted the author? There is no information for us to work with really

Comment: I contacted author, he told me that this issue needs serious custom coding. This is Mixtape WordPress Theme. There is no plugin for it (maybe SliderRevolution), whole slider/event is built in into theme.